# Postgresql set default boolean to null with yes/no

Tags: dbeaver

In Postgresql 11 when I run the following the result is a true/false option for the column when I view this in dbeaver. Is it possible to specify a boolean column with default value null using yes/no?

```sql
ALTER TABLE buildings
    ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS ownership_historic boolean DEFAULT null;
```

Clarification to yes/no, as below on dbeaver the column input value is showing as a true false option whereas I want a yes/no option. This might be a dbeaver display preference?

[image]

Comment: Can you clarify last part "...using yes/no" ?

Comment: Added to OP in response to your question

Comment: You have values stored as booleans, so it can be either 1) true, 2) false or 3) without value (NULL). I am not sure, it seems your question is more about why dbeaver can't show yes/no instead of true/false? Or you are more how to *store* Yes/No in postgres ?